# Swift: How to set functions to each specific marker?

Tags: swift, function, google-maps, navigation, google-maps-markers

In the following code, I need to set each specific marker to a function. How do I set the function to: When MarkerInfoWindow is tapped, then open URL? The URL needs to be specific for each marker.

**The idea** is when MarkerInfoWindow is tapped for marker1, then it should show navigations for this marker1.

**The question** is how I re-write this code to make the function specific for each marker

Marker 1:

```
let marker1 = GMSMarker()
marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.6726299, longitude: 12.5662175)
marker1.title = "Københavns Hovedbanegård"
marker1.snippet = "Press for navigation"
marker1.tracksViewChanges = true
marker1.opacity = 0.9
marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "BCmarker")
marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone
marker1.map = self.googleMapsView
```

Marker 2:

```
let marker2 = GMSMarker()
marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.68, longitude: 12.55)
marker2.title = "Test Marker2"
marker2.snippet = "Press for navigation"
marker2.tracksViewChanges = true
marker2.opacity = 0.9
marker2.icon = UIImage(named: "BCmarker")
marker2.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone
marker2.map = self.googleMapsView
```

Function that each marker specifically shall be assigned:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
let testURL = URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(testURL) {
    let directionsRequest = "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
    "?daddr=55.6726299,12.5662175&directionsmode=walking&zoom=17"

    let directionsURL = URL(string: directionsRequest)!
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(directionsURL)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?address=1600,PennsylvaniaAve.,20500")! as URL)
}
```

Thank you!

After the answer from @Sweeper, this is how the code looks like:
    import UIKit
    import GoogleMaps
    import GooglePlaces

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate, GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

// OUTLETS!
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapsView: GMSMapView!

// VARIABLES!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // GET LOCATION WHILE USING APP
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    initGoogleMaps()
}


    // START GOOGLE MAPS!
func initGoogleMaps() {

    let zoomCamera = GMSCameraUpdate.zoomIn()
    googleMapsView.animate(with: zoomCamera)

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 55.6760968, longitude: 12.568337100000008, zoom: 12.5)
    _ = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    self.googleMapsView.camera = camera

    // CREATE FIND LOCATION BUTTON??
    self.googleMapsView.delegate = self
    self.googleMapsView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.googleMapsView.settings.myLocationButton = true

    // MARKERS
    let marker1 = GMSMarker()
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.6726299, longitude: 12.5662175)
    marker1.title = "Københavns Hovedbanegård"
    marker1.snippet = "Tryk for at få navigation"
    marker1.tracksViewChanges = true
    marker1.opacity = 0.9
    marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "BCmarker")
    marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone
    marker1.map = self.googleMapsView

    let marker2 = GMSMarker()
    marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.68, longitude: 12.55)
    marker2.title = "Test Marker2"
    marker2.snippet = "Tryk for at få navigation"
    marker2.tracksViewChanges = true
    marker2.opacity = 0.9
    marker2.icon = UIImage(named: "BCmarker")
    marker2.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone
    marker2.map = self.googleMapsView

    let markerFunctions: [GMSMarker: (() -> Void)] = [
        marker1: { print("Test1") },
            marker2: { print("Test2") }
    ]

}

// ...something else about Google Places
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker)` will be called when *any* marker's info window is tapped. You want to get a specific one that will only be called when a *specific* marker's info window is tapped. Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

There is no such delegate method in the Google Maps API unfortunately.

Well, the simple workaround will just be to use an if statement to check whether it is `marker1` or `marker2`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
    if marker == marker1 { // remember to declare marker 1 and 2 at class level!
        // do stuff
    } else if marker == marker2 {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can put the stuff you want each marker to do in a dictionary:

```
let markerFuntions: [GMSMarker: (() -> Void)] = [
    marker1: { // do stuff }
    marker2: { // do other stuff }
]
```

You can then just write the delegate method like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
    markerFunctions[marker]?()
}
```

EDIT: I tried to fix the problems with your code, here's what I got:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate, GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

// OUTLETS!
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapsView: GMSMapView!

// VARIABLES!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var marker1: GMSMarker!
var marker2: GMSMarker!
var markerFunctions: [GMSMarker: (() -> Void)]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // GET LOCATION WHILE USING APP
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    initGoogleMaps()
}


    // START GOOGLE MAPS!
func initGoogleMaps() {

    let zoomCamera = GMSCameraUpdate.zoomIn()
    googleMapsView.animate(with: zoomCamera)

    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 55.6760968, longitude: 12.568337100000008, zoom: 12.5)
    _ = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    self.googleMapsView.camera = camera

    // CREATE FIND LOCATION BUTTON??
    self.googleMapsView.delegate = self
    self.googleMapsView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    self.googleMapsView.settings.myLocationButton = true

    // MARKERS
    marker1 = GMSMarker()
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.6726299, longitude: 12.5662175)
    marker1.title = "Københavns Hovedbanegård"
    marker1.snippet = "Tryk for at få navigation"
    marker1.tracksViewChanges = true
    marker1.opacity = 0.9
    marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "BCmarker")
    marker1.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone
    marker1.map = self.googleMapsView

    marker2 = GMSMarker()
    marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.68, longitude: 12.55)
    marker2.title = "Test Marker2"
    marker2.snippet = "Tryk for at få navigation"
    marker2.tracksViewChanges = true
    marker2.opacity = 0.9
    marker2.icon = UIImage(named: "BCmarker")
    marker2.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationNone
    marker2.map = self.googleMapsView

    markerFunctions = [
        marker1: { print("Test1") },
        marker2: { print("Test2") }
    ]

}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
    markerFunctions[marker]?()
}

// ...something else about Google Places
```

Comment: Hi @Sweeper
I have added "let markerFunctions...." below the marker and added the function in the "AppDelegate file" but the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'markerFuntions'... shows up. 
What can I do to avoid this? 
(All Targets are checked in "Target Membership".)

Comment: @ChristofferSkov why not declare the individual functions in the same class as the map view delegate? Can you edit the question to add the relevant code?

Comment: I have edited the question so you can see the full text. Please notice that the function still is in the "AppDelegate"-file.
Here the code is as follows:
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
        markerFunctions[marker]?()
    }

Comment: I forgot to tag you.

Comment: @ChristofferSkov you need to move the declarations of the markers and the dictionary outside `initGoogleMaps`. Also, set `ViewController` as the map's delegate instead of the AppDelegate. This is basic variable scoping stuff. I think you should establish a solid foundation of programming first, before you start doing google maps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I know. I am pretty new at coding in swift. The reason why I moved the map delegate in the app delegate was because I just tried everything to make it work. It did not help.
Right now, to get this function to work is the last thing before I am done. Can you help me to make this work? How do I write the code to make the function work?
FYI I am developing this for free to benefit many people in Copenhagen.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: For @Sweeper to see above comment

Comment: @ChristofferSkov I've given you the full code. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been working on the code for a while now. As it is now, I have over 100 of markers to be placed. I have tried JSON but cannot figure out how to reference using my own code.

How to I reference each marker to this below example in the JSON-file? Or are there any other easier way to do it? Thanks!

        "Marker": 6,
        "Streetname": "Balders Plads",
        "Longitude": 12.548306498695576,
        "latitude": 55.70121805912661,
        "Station": "XXXXX"

@Sweeper

Comment: For @Sweeper to see above comment

Comment: @ChristofferSkov first of all that's out of the scope of this question and I don't really know much about JSON. Try to use a library like SwiftyJSON.